# ASP.NET combined with MS-Word

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Microsoft Word document which contains several objects such as `TextBox` and `DropDownList`.

I also have a ASP.NET application build with some textboxes. I want to retrieve the textbox value from Microsoft Word and read it into the corresponding textbox in asp and also for the dropdownlist. I have managed the other way around using textbox in asp and bookmarks in Word:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document
        'Start Word and Open document template
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = True
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("D:\worddoctest\asptest.docx")
        oDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range.Text = TextBox1.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks("address").Range.Text = TextBox2.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks("postal code").Range.Text = TextBox3.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks("email").Range.Text = TextBox4.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks("country").Range.Text = TextBox5.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you have Word installed on the server? If so, it's really, really not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information.